# CMake WxWidgets project successfully built on linux but not on windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

I've managed to build a WxWidgets based on CMake on Ubuntu 19.10, but failed on Windows 10, saying that it cannot find WxWidgets, though I've built it successfully (static, release and with unicode support).

WxWidgets path is `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.3` and the build directory is `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.3\msw-release`.

The makefile is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(ChessPgnReviser VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Wall -Wno-sign-compare -O2)

set(SRCS
    src/main.cpp
)

set (HEADERS
)

message( "--Root--" ${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR} )
message( "--Lib dir--" ${wxWidgets_LIB_DIR} )

add_executable(ChessPgnReviser ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})

find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS net gl core base)
if(wxWidgets_FOUND)
  include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
  target_link_libraries(ChessPgnReviser ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find WxWidgets library")
endif()
```

I'm using Msys 64 bit in order to compile the project. At the bottom of its subfolder etc/profile, I've added

```
PATH=$PATH:/c/dev/cmake/bin
wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.3
wxWidgets_LIBRARIES=$wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR/msw-release/lib
wxWidgets_LIB_DIR=$wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR/msw-release/lib
wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS=$wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR/include
```

So I've tried

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
--Root--
--Lib dir--
-- Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS net gl core base)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (message):
  Failed to find WxWidgets library


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/laure/Documents/Programmation/ProjetsPersos/Cpp/ChessPgnReviserWxWidgets/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Also, thanks to @squareskittles, I also tried:

```
$ cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DwxWidgets_ROOT_DIR="C:\wxWidgets-3.1.3" -DwxWidgets_LIB_DIR="C:\wxWidgets-3.1.3\msw-release\lib"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
--Root--C:\wxWidgets-3.1.3
--Lib dir--C:\wxWidgets-3.1.3\msw-release\lib
-- Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS net gl core base)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (message):
  Failed to find WxWidgets library


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/laure/Documents/Programmation/ProjetsPersos/Cpp/ChessPgnReviserWxWidgets/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

You can find the content of the msw-release folder : [there](https://pastebin.com/XgscjS9G).

Also:

```
$ ls /c/wxWidgets-3.1.3/msw-release/lib/
libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a  libwx_baseu-3.1.a     libwx_mswu_aui-3.1.a   libwx_mswu_gl-3.1.a    libwx_mswu_media-3.1.a     libwx_mswu_qa-3.1.a      libwx_mswu_richtext-3.1.a  libwx_mswu_webview-3.1.a  libwxregexu-3.1.a     wx
libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.a  libwx_mswu_adv-3.1.a  libwx_mswu_core-3.1.a  libwx_mswu_html-3.1.a  libwx_mswu_propgrid-3.1.a  libwx_mswu_ribbon-3.1.a  libwx_mswu_stc-3.1.a       libwx_mswu_xrc-3.1.a      libwxscintilla-3.1.a
```

So did I forget something ?

Comment: How are you calling the `cmake` command on the command line? I ask because the CMake log file is put on the path `C:/Users...` using Windows formatting, but your `wxWidgets_*` variables are using the path `/c/` with Unix-style formatting. This makes me think the variables are not visible to CMake, have you verified they are visible? Have you tried setting the wxWidget path as a CMake command line argument instead? `cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DwxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=C:/wxWidgets-3.1.3`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it did not work. Please, see my edited post. Also I managed to make calls like `ls $wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR`.

Comment: I remember from having the same problem that you need to **build twice** to go past some errors when building wxWidgets, maybe this thread (https://github.com/rhiestan/Regard3D/issues/17) can help you when building twice does not work.

Comment: If detection used `wx-config` you can try installing https://github.com/kowey/wx-config-win . To tell it where your wxWidgets is you need set environment variable `WXWIN` to `C:/wxWidgets-3.1.3` and `WXCFG` to something like `msw\gcc_mswu`.

Comment: Hi @BrechtSanders. Indeed I need wx-config, which I've installed, as cmake function FindWxWidgets is based on wx-config. However, I am still trying to make it work with my cmake script, so that the build could succeed. I've set up WXWIN and WXCFG variables.

Comment: Hi @BrechtSanders ! I managed to compile with your recommandations and wx-config. Could you post your comment as an answer ? I'll accept it and reward you bounties. And I have also some precisions to give regarding my configuration. As also I had build wxwidgets in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly detect wxWidgets you need `wx-config`.

A Windows version of `wx-config` exists and can be downloaded from: https://github.com/kowey/wx-config-win

To make `wx-config` know where your wxWidgets is, you need set the following environment variables:

- `WXWIN` (in your case to `C:/wxWidgets-3.1.3`)
- `WXCFG` (in your case to something `like msw/gcc_mswu`).

Comment: Thank you. I also had to recompile wxWidgets so that the static libraries are set in the sub-folder msw/gcc_mswu. For that, I went into the folder msw and compiled with mingw32-make.exe instead of creating the msw-release folder myself. That way and setting wx-config to the path, it worked.

Comment: @loloof64 I built wxWidgets without shared dlls, both debug and release. I don't have the msw/gcc_mswu folder to specify for the WXCFG variable. Is this a must? \bin folder: has wx-config.exe , wxrc.exe. \lib has \*mswu\*.a files

Comment: @VaisakMohan check lib/gcc_lib (or lib/gcc_dll for shared build). Normally you should find something like `msw/build.cfg` / `mswd/build.cfg` / `mswu/build.cfg` / `mswud/build.cfg` in there. That's what you should specify in `WXCFG`.

Comment: There is nowhere a file named build.cfg in wxWidgets install folder.( Here is my folder tree: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jvy9zzVTzC/). When I type just "wx-config --libs --cflags" into the windows terminal, it gives error:
wx-config Error: wxWidgets hasn't been found installed at 'X:\SYSTEM\wxWidgets'.

Comment: @VaisakMohan Is that tree actually the Windows build of wxWidgets? Normally the install folder will contain build.cfg...

Comment: Yes. I used Cmake upon the windows source files of wxWidgets (using SHARED=0, and USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=1). Configured and generated debug and release. Then used mingw32-make and then mingw32-make install on both of them

Comment: Then you will probably need to manually install `build.cfg`